# Can a Flash .swf banner upgrade its graphics from an URL by itself?

Tags: flash, dynamic-data

I created a Flash .swf banner, it has 4 different photos and swf shows these 4 photos.

But these 4 photos must be upgraded. Is it possible to make that automatically? I mean flash swf will connect to an URL, and it will take 4 random photos from the URL and it will upgrade itself. And it will do this every week.

If it is possible, can you tell me how, and can you describe it please?

Thanks.

Elias

Comment: current code of your swf would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the easiest way to go but I think this scenario will work.

Use a file to keep track of last update (date).
Use a file to keep the url of the current images.
Make sure the .swf can access thess files, reading and writing.
Make sure the .swf van read all other folders and files needed

In .swf file

- read the file with the date of last update
- check if update is needed
- if so write today's date to update file
- read the image folder
- randomly pick your files (only if there are more than 4 files)
- write new images urls to file with imageurls
- display images

Making changes manually would just involve adjusting the file that holds the urls of the images

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am a beginner and I must confess that I do not understand your solution. Not even a word! My bad. can you explain it step by step?
 
For exapmle:

1.Create a .htm file through notepad
2.Right click on it and click "Open with".

I am sorry for my English too :)

Comment: I am sorry it made no sense. This is a little out of your league right now. You need a step by step walkthrough that is out of the scope of this forum